# Hibernate: @OneToMany - additional condtions? @Filter?

Tags: hibernate, filter

In our Database we have a lot of Objects that are *shared* between Users. For Instance `Contacts`, `Customers`, `Companies`, etc...

There are also a lot of *private* Objects, that are mapped to one of the *shared* entity, but should be visible only to the user that created it - for example *Notes*

Our Customer Entity contains a `@OneToMany` Mapping for `Notes` and `Contacts`

```
@Entity
public Class Customer{

    @OneToMany
    Set<Contact> contacts;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Note> notes;
}
```

Currently I would need to load thausands of notes, just to figure out : The current user has no note for that customer...

So i thought about something to "filter" the collection before loading it - and indeed, Hibernate does support the `@Filter` annotation for that purpose (it seems), so, I would need to apply the following annotation as well:

```
    @OneToMany
    @Filter(name="userIdFilter", condition=" :userIdFromSession = userId")
    Set<Note> notes;
```

But on everything else, the documentation leaves some questions. Every example now continues with showing how to set the filters value (`:userIdFromSession`), when using `session.createQuery()`

```
Session session = ...;
session.enableFilter("userIdFilter").setParameter("userIdFromSession", session.getUser().getId());
List results = session.createQuery(...)
```

But **how** can I enable the filter (and set the targetvalue) when using the Entity-Manager along with `em.find()`, sot the target value is "applied" for every Filter condition in the Object-Tree?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. Due to the project layout it is a little more tricky and *hacky* than expected, but after all the final result is now exactly what I expected from the change:

**No matter how i'm going to load entities (Service, Lazy initalization) Hibernate is applying the user-id filter whenever loading *private* entities.**

#### Filter Definition

First, the definition of the `Filter` requires an additional annotation: `@FilterDef` on one of the entities:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "userFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "user", type = "java.lang.Integer"), defaultCondition = "user_id = :user")
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
```

The Filter now can be applied to any Collection in order to let Hibernate apply the filter:

```
@OneToMany
@Filter(name="userFilter")
Set<Note> notes;
```

#### EntityManager

As outlined in the question I'm using the EntityManager which has no exposed methods for the filters. However, since we can get the actual `Session` from the EntityManager, I was able to enable the filter like this (This needs to be done everytime you obtain a new EntityManager Instance (or let's say, when the prior Session has been closed)):

```
org.hibernate.Session sess = (org.hibernate.Session) this.em.getDelegate();
sess.enableFilter("userFilter").setParameter("user", this.session.getCurrentUser().getId());
```

#### User?

Now the tricky part: First Hibernate was running in Circles throwing exceptions and not working at all. This is where the project dependent setting comes into play. I'm using a *generic* Dataservice to handle stuff like `fetchAll, fetchByPK, save, ...`

So the method(s) looked like this at first:

```
public <T> LinkedList<T> fetchAll(Class<T> clazz) {
    LinkedList<T> result = new LinkedList<>();
    org.hibernate.Session sess = (org.hibernate.Session) this.em.getDelegate();
    sess.enableFilter("userFilter").setParameter("user", this.session.getCurrentUser().getId());
    result = new LinkedList<T>(this.em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " x", clazz).getResultList());
    return result;
}
```

Since I used the very same approach to fetch the `User` itself - I ended up with a loop, cause everytime I tried to setup the filter, Hibernate tried to initialize *my* session and fetching an user object - which in turn tried the same again.

Solution ofc. was to exclude the fetching of `User.class` from enabling filters:

```
public <T> LinkedList<T> fetchAll(Class<T> clazz) {
    LinkedList<T> result = new LinkedList<>();
    org.hibernate.Session sess = (org.hibernate.Session) this.em.getDelegate();
    if (clazz != User.class) {
        sess.enableFilter("userFilter").setParameter("user", this.session.getCurrentUser().getId());
    } else {
        sess.disableFilter("userFilter");
    }
    result = new LinkedList<T>(this.em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " x", clazz).getResultList());
    return result;
}
```

(this also works along with `em.find`)

#### LazyLoading

All my Collections are loaded lazy, and since this might happen during Ajax Requests as well, I needed to use multiple sessions across the project.

To ensure the `initializeCollection()` Method used for LazyLoading applies the very Same filters, I had to modify it, again taking into account, that there are *LazyLoaded* Collections inside the User Object itself.

So, to avoid a endless loop in case of LazyLoading *and* having all other sessions to use the filter as well, I just applied the principle used in the Generic DataService. (the method to initialize collections is part of the most abstract Entity which is the parent for all entities)

```
User u = null;
if (this instanceof User) {
    u = (User) this;
} else {
    u = ContextHelper.getBean("mysession", my.namespace.Session.class).getCurrentUser();
}

//...

newSession.enableFilter("userFilter").setParameter("user", u.getId());
```

The only drawback of evaluating EL-Expressions (Helper.getBean) from within an entity is that this entity is now literaly *wired* to be only used when the `FacesContext` is available. But for the scope of this Project, that can be guaranteed, so not really a limitation. (this is also more a reason of the way I designed the lazy initialization rather than caused by *using filters*)